# log4net - errors when is called as a Component Service

Tags: c#, log4net, component-services

I've created a .Net object (it is a basic logger composed by log4net and log4net.Ext.Json). This .Net  object is added to Component Services as COM+ Application to make it accessible for some legacy systems.

In order to test this component service, I've created a console application in C# that will create a instance of the object and then will invoke my desired method `LogMessage`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    COMAdminCatalogCollection applications;
    COMAdminCatalog catalog;
        
    catalog = new COMAdminCatalog();
    applications = (COMAdminCatalogCollection)catalog.GetCollection("Applications");
    applications.Populate();

    foreach (COMAdminCatalogObject application in applications)
    {
        if (application.Name.Equals("MyApplicationName"))
        {
            COMAdminCatalogCollection components;
            components = applications.GetCollection("Components", application.Key);
            components.Populate();

            foreach (COMAdminCatalogObject component in components)
            {
                var instance = ComObjectGet(component.Name);

            }
        }
    }
}

public static object ComObjectGet(string componentName)
{
    Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(componentName);
    var COMobject = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    var COMobjectType = Activator.CreateInstance(type).GetType();
    MethodInfo getAllMethod = COMobjectType.GetMethod("LogMessage");
    object result = getAllMethod.Invoke(COMobject, new object[] { "First param", "Second param", "Third param" });

    return COMobject;
}
```

When line `var COMobject = Activator.CreateInstance(type);` is executed, o get this error:

> log4net:ERROR Failed to create object to set param: layout
> log4net:ERROR Failed to find type [log4net.Layout.SerializedLayout,
> log4net.Ext.Json] System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or
> assembly 'log4net, Version=2.0.9.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a' or one of its dependencies. The
> located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
> reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I'm using `log4net.Ext.Json` because I need to write logs in json format, however, when I modify my log4Net configuration file to use default appender, it works as expected, so my guess is that there is a problem with `log4net.Ext.Json`. This is my log4Net configuration file:

```
<configuration>
    <log4net debug="true">
        <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
            <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="C:\Logs\MyLog_JSON.log" name ="RollingLogFileAppender" />
            <appendToFile value="true" />
            <rollingStyle value="Date" />
            <countDirection value="-1"/>
            <datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <staticLogFileName value="true" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.SerializedLayout, log4net.Ext.Json">
                <member value="logDateTime%date:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:ffff" />
                <decorator type="log4net.Layout.Decorators.StandardTypesDecorator, log4net.Ext.Json" />
                <member value="hostName" />
                <default />
                <remove value="date" />
                <remove value="ndc" />
                <remove value="message" />
                <remove value="thread" />
                <remove value="exception" />
                <member value="logData:messageObject" />
            </layout>
        </appender>
        <root>
            <level value="All"/>
            <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender"/>
        </root>
    </log4net>
</configuration>
```

I saw that this issue could be solved by calling `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();` but it my case it didn't work and I set log4net in debug mode `<log4net debug="true">`, as well, but there aren't new clues to find a solution, I just get the same references error.

One thing to mention is that I debug my .Net component directly in Visual Studio and all the things work as expected, the error comes when the object is called as COM+ Application.

Comment: Which version of log4net does your component reference? log4net.Ext.Json Version 2.0.10.1 references log4net Version 2.0.9.0 and if this is not the version you reference you might get this error. Either use the same version of add a binding redirect.

Comment: @KlausGütter log4net.Ext.Json version cannot be higher than log4net version. Currently I'm using log4net version 2.0.9 and log4net.Ext.Json version 2.0.8.3